# Postgresql create database with size & resize?

Tags: postgresql, size, auto-growth

My question regards **PostgreSQL database size.**

How can I create new database with fixed size? (e.g. 5 GB)

Once I have created fixed sized PostgreSQL database, how can I resize it ?

Comment: It sounds like you want *database quotas*. If so, PostgreSQL doesn't support them. You can create the database on a file system limited to the desired size, but MVCC and write-ahead logging will mean it won't work how you expect. The short version is "you can't".

Comment: @CraigRinger how about putting the (default) tablespace on a restricted-size volume?  This, at least, would remove the WAL from the equation.

Comment: Yeah, but the *whole cluster* will stop until you free some space, and you can't free space without adding more space first. So it's not going to work well.

Answer (score 2):

As we can read in the comments, there is no direct support in postgresql for this - but you can solve this problem with indirect means, as you can read here: http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/421532-database-size-limiting

Basically, you have various options to make a separate database instance, or a cluster node, or a partition, and then limit the disk usage on the OS level (f.e. user quotas).

AFAIK in case of a quota exhaust your transactions will be rollbacked, but the db left consistent. But I suggest to doublecheck this before you do some dangerous.